# initMap is not a function - map not rendering. Google Maps API - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am experiencing the well known issue `initMap is not a function` and I really don't see how to solve it. I've tried various methods recommended in other questions but none of them work. The only plausible solution I found was involving the usage of **AngularJS** but I am trying to accomplish script without it.

Here is my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    
        <script async defer 
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXX&callback=initMap"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src ="script.js" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href ="style.css">
</head>
    <body>
    <div id ="map-canvas"> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
window.initMap = function() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      };
```

For the JS code, I literally copied and pasted what's in Google's documentation with a small change made here `window.initMap = function()`.

---

Things I've tried:

1. Changing `function initMap()` to `window.initMap = function()`
2. Delete everything in `initMap()` and giving it `alert("ok")` to see
   if it will come up. Well, it didn't.
3. Changed the position of `async defer` to the end of the script reference, also put the script reference at the very top.

Questions I've checked in detail:

[First try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795150/uncaught-invalidvalueerror-initmap-is-not-a-function), [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617503/google-maps-api-initmap-is-not-a-function), [Third time wasn't the charm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770157/invalidvalueerror-initmap-is-not-a-function)

The error message I get :

[image: Error-msg-Chrome]

**My map is not being rendered and I keep getting this error, any ideas how to fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Add the missing `</script>` tag
2. Change the order of the page load:

```
<div id="map-canvas"> </div>
<script src="script.js" defer async></script>
<script async defer 
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXX&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why it doesn't read `<script src="script.js" />`  ?

Comment: That is not legal HTML (the script tag is not self closing)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of the scripts from this

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    
        <script async defer 
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXX&callback=initMap"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src ="script.js" />
```

To this

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    

        <script src ="script.js" />
        <script async defer 
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXX&callback=initMap"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

So this way the `initMap` function is defined before the GMaps api loads

Comment: that removed the Error, thanks but my map is still not being rendered for some reason.