# Google map keeps on giving me the same error

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm trying to insert a google map tp my html code but it keeps on giving me this error: "myMap is not a function", here is my code:

```js
function myMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.12),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}
```

```css
#map{
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY4&callback=myMap"></script>
```

Comment: Did you place the `myMap` function before the `<script>` tag?

Comment: no its in a separate js file

Comment: If so, did you load that "separate" file before you load the `google maps` script?

Comment: duplicate of [initMap is not a function - map not rendering. Google Maps API - JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660124/initmap-is-not-a-function-map-not-rendering-google-maps-api-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code works as is if the code snippet is rearranged to define the `myMap` function before the include of the API.  Note that you don't (currently) need a key on stackoverflow.com as it is grandfathered with keyless access.

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function myMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.12),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize the actual map. Try the following. (it'll throw errors as I removed the API Key)

```js
function myMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.12),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', myMap);
```

```css
#map{
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY4&callback=myMap"></script>
```

Comment: it worked thank you! but it gave me this error in the console Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined, is that okay?

Comment: @stephjhonny Make sure the <script src='http://maps.googleapis... </script> Is above the myMap function.

Comment: @stephjhonny keep that line after  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY4&callback=myMap"></script>

Comment: You don't need both `callback=myMap` and `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', myMap);`